# Tight layout using Cartopy without passing w_pad argument?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, cartopy

When using `tight_layout` with Cartopy and multiple subplots the result is not a tight layout. Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
   
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2,2)

fig = plt.figure()
for k in range(0,4):
    ax = plt.subplot(gs[k], projection = ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.set_extent([0,50,0,90])
    ax.coastlines()
gs.tight_layout(fig)
```

produces a figure with wide gap between each map:

[image: Wide gap example]

The same issue occurs when using pyplot's `tight_layout`, whether I set the `ax.set_extent()` or not, the result is not as expected. Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fig, ((ax1,ax2),(ax3,ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2,
                             subplot_kw=dict(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()))
for ax in fig.axes:
    ax.coastlines()
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: Overlapped example]

While I can adjust this manually on both cases by using `w_pad` and `h_pad` arguments on `tight_layout`, I would have to do this manually for every figure depending on the amount of subplots and/or the map itself. Is there any way to do this without these arguments, or to automatically determine what these values should be? Or maybe automatically set the figure size?

Using Linux 5.4.0-40-generic, Python 3.7.6 64-bit, Cartopy 0.18.0, Matplotlib 3.2.2

**Edit:**

The question is how to reproduce the `tight_layout` function using Cartopy without needing to manually set the `w_pad` or `h_pad` depending on what I'm plotting.

Currently, I'm creating many different figures, changing:

- Projections: some are PlateCarree, some are Polar Stereographic
- Map extent: entire map, reduced lat/lon on PlateCarree, reduced latitudes on Polar Stereographic
- Different amount of rows/cols: 1 to 7 rows, 1 to 5 columns.
- Adding latitudes and longitudes ticks on the first column and the last row, a title to each column, an `y_label` on the first column, and an overall title.
- Depending on the figure, adding a colorbar on the right of each row.

The end result should be figures that have consistent horizontal and vertical space between each subplot and the different figures, like the expected result of `tight_layout`.

Example code with all the above, following @swatchai answer:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER
from cartopy.examples.waves import sample_data
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes

ar = 1.0  # initial aspect ratio for first trial
wi = 5   # width in inches
hi = wi * ar  # height in inches

# set number of rows/columns
rows, cols = 2,2
# set projection
# proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
proj = ccrs.NorthPolarStereo()
# set lon/lat extent
# extent = [0,50,0,90] # example for PlateCarree
# extent = [-180,180,-90,90] # complete map
extent = [-180,180,30,90] # example for PolarStereo

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(rows, cols)

# Set figsize using wi and hi
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(wi, hi))
for r in range(0,rows):
    for c in range(0,cols):
        ax = plt.subplot(gs[r,c], projection = proj)
        ax.set_extent(extent,ccrs.PlateCarree())
        ax.coastlines()
        
        # Add sample data
        x, y, z = sample_data((20, 40))
        z = z * -1.5 * y
        cf = ax.contourf(x, y, z, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
        
        # Add colorbar
        if c == cols -1:
            axins = inset_axes(ax,
                    bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 0., 1, 1),
                    width='5%',height='98%',loc='lower left',
                    bbox_transform=ax.transAxes,
                    borderpad=0)
             
            cbar = fig.colorbar(cf, cax=axins,orientation='vertical')
           
        # Gridlines, labels, titles
        if r == 0:
            ax.set_title('column title')
        if c == 0:
            ax.set_ylabel('y label')
            ax.set_yticks([])
        if proj == ccrs.PlateCarree():
            gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=False, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
            gl.xformatter, gl.yformatter  = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER,  LATITUDE_FORMATTER
            if r == rows-1:
                gl.xlabels_bottom = True
            if c == 0:
                gl.ylabels_left = True 
                ax.set_ylabel('y label',labelpad=35)
                ax.set_yticks([])
        elif proj == ccrs.NorthPolarStereo():
            ax.gridlines()
plt.suptitle('A figure title')
        
        
# Do this to get updated positions/dimensions   
plt.draw() 

# # Get proper ratio here
# # Computed from the last `ax` (being the current)
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xbound()
ymin, ymax = ax.get_ybound()
y2x_ratio = (ymax-ymin)/(xmax-xmin) * rows/cols

# # Apply new h/w aspect ratio by changing h
# # Also possible to change w using set_figwidth()
fig.set_figheight(wi * y2x_ratio)

gs.tight_layout(fig)
plt.show()
```

The above produces graphs that have very different horizontal/vertical gaps depending on the amount of subplots/projections. The labels, titles, etc are also sometimes out of proportion for the overall figure (which doesn't happen when `tight_layout` works as intended). Some are also rotated. E.g., using the above code with `rows, cols = 3, 4`, `PlateCarree()` and the complete map plotted, gives:

[image: Big horizontal/vertical gaps, rotated axis]

Comment: I forgot to mention that `wi = 5` in my code is the total width (in inches) of the whole figure that user must specify to accomodate all the subplots. In your last plot, 5 is clearly too small, `wi = 17` should yield better plots. Remember, you always need some reasonable dimensions to start with.

Comment: @swatchai I understand. How did you come up with 17 being the correct number for this particular plot? Try and error? If yes, then what would be the benefits of using this code and adjusting the width manually versus manually adjusting the parameters `w_pad` and `h_pad` on `tight_layout`?

Comment: In this particular case, any reasonably large value, say, 15-20 is big enough to fit 4 columns of plots (or 3+ inches per column). Larger does not  hurt. If you don't use `inset_axes()`, the step `tight_layout()` will adjust overall dimensions nicely in most cases. The use of `inset_axes()` disrupts the function of `tight_layout()` thus not allow to use some of its options, including `w_pad` and `h_pad`. Over all dimensions of the figure (w and h) must be specified by the user (or skip and use the default). I define only `width`, while `height` is computed programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

To get better plots you must declare `figsize` with proper width and height in such a way that the height/width ratio matches the subplot sizes. It is possible to compute the ratio programmatically in the code, then apply it as an update value and get the plots as needed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

# use figsize=(w,h) of proper values can give good result
# the aspect ratio, h/w is important
# default is around 1, is good in general, but not in your case

ar = 1.0  # initial aspect ratio for first trial
wi = 5    # width in inches
hi = wi * ar  # height in inches

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2,2)

# Set figsize using wi and hi
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(wi, hi))  

for k in range(0,4):
    ax = plt.subplot(gs[k], projection = ccrs.PlateCarree())  
    # any of these projections are OK to use
    # PlateCarree() Robinson() Mercator() TransverseMercator() Orthographic()
    ax.set_extent([0,50,0,90])
    ax.coastlines()
    ax.gridlines()

# Do this to get updated positions/dimensions   
plt.draw() 

# Get proper ratio here
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xbound()
ymin, ymax = ax.get_ybound()
y2x_ratio = (ymax-ymin)/(xmax-xmin)

# This also gives same ratio
#x1, x2 = ax.get_xlim()
#y1, y2 = ax.get_ylim()
#y2x_ratio = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

print("y2x_ratio: "+ str(y2x_ratio)) 
#1.8258 with Robinson; 1.8 PlateCarree; 3.37 Mercator; 1.549 TransverseMercator

# Apply new h/w aspect ratio by changing h
# Also possible to change w using set_figwidth()
fig.set_figheight(wi * y2x_ratio)

gs.tight_layout(fig)
plt.show()
```

The output plot:

[image: 2x2maps]

**Edit 1**

The original answer concentrates on an array of 2x2 (rows x columns). For other array, the computation of aspect ratio must be changed to account for it. Here is an update version of runnable code and sample plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

# use figsize=(w,h) of proper values can give good result
# the aspect ratio, h/w is important
# default is around 1, is good in general cases

ar = 1.0  # initial aspect ratio for first trial
wi = 5    # width of the whole figure in inches, ...
# set it wide enough to cover all columns of sub-plots

hi = wi * ar  # height in inches

# set number of rows/columns
rows, cols = 4,3

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(rows, cols)

# Set figsize using wi and hi
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(wi, hi))

for k in range(0, rows*cols):
    ax = plt.subplot(gs[k], projection = ccrs.Robinson())  
    # any of these projections are OK to use
    # PlateCarree() Robinson() Mercator() Orthographic()
    #ax.set_extent([0,50,0,90])
    ax.coastlines()
    ax.gridlines()

# Do this to get updated positions/dimensions   
plt.draw() 

# Get proper ratio here
# Computed from the last `ax` (being the current)
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xbound()
ymin, ymax = ax.get_ybound()
y2x_ratio = (ymax-ymin)/(xmax-xmin) * rows/cols

# Apply new h/w aspect ratio by changing h
# Also possible to change w using set_figwidth()
fig.set_figheight(wi * y2x_ratio)

gs.tight_layout(fig)
plt.show()
```

The output plot:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I can't seem to make this work when I plot the entire map (no `ax.set_extent`). This is particularly noticeable when using more subplots (e.g. 4 rows x 3 columns). I also tried adding a `fig.set_figwidth(...)` with `x2x_ratio = 1/y2x_ratio` and other combinations of the variable `wi`. This helped in the cases where `ax.set_extent` is used and with different amount of subplots, but doesn't seem to be enough with the entire map plotted.

Comment: I appreciate the update. While this works better, it still leaves different horizontal/vertical gaps depending on the projection, the extent of the map, and the amount of subplots. I can't seem to find a good `fig.set_figwidth(...)` either, since changing this also changes the vertical gap. Maybe I'm missing something? Otherwise, adapting this to every plot seems harder than to just use a custom `w_pad` and `h_pad`.

Comment: @lanadaquenada Please state all your requirements in your questions clearly. A custom plot like this has many details to handle.

Comment: I edited the question, I hope it is now clear enough.